# First time writing tests (Service Layer)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocks

Service class:

```
package personal.progresscompaninon.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import personal.progresscompaninon.dto.PasswordChangeDto;
import personal.progresscompaninon.exception.*;
import personal.progresscompaninon.model.Role;
import personal.progresscompaninon.model.User;
import personal.progresscompaninon.repository.RoleRepository;
import personal.progresscompaninon.repository.UserRepository;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

public void addUser(@Valid User user) {
        if (findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null) {

            throw new UserAlreadyRegisteredException("User already registered");

        }
        user.getRoles().add(roleRepository.findByRole("ROLE_USER"));
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public void changePassword(@Valid PasswordChangeDto passwords) {
        User user = getLoggedInUser();
        if (bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(passwords.getOldPassword(), user.getPassword())) {
            if (passwordValidator(passwords.getNewPassword())) {
                userRepository.changePassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(passwords.getNewPassword()), user.getEmail());
                System.out.println(user.getPassword());
            }
        } else {
            throw new WrongPasswordException("Old password didn't match");
        }
    }

    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }


    public boolean passwordValidator(String password) {
        return password.length() > 8;
    }

    public User getLoggedInUser() {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
    }


    public User getUser(long id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id).get();
    }


    public void deleteUser(long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }


@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found in the database");
        }
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }
```

Tests:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepositoryMock;
    @Mock
    private RoleRepository roleRepositoryMock;
    private UserService userService;


    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        userService = new UserService(userRepositoryMock, roleRepositoryMock);
    }

    @Test
    void shouldAddUser() {
        String role = "ROLE_USER";
        User user = new User(0L, "test", "test", "yes@gmail.com", "yesyesyes", new ArrayList<>(), null);
        Mockito.when(roleRepositoryMock.findByRole(role)).thenReturn(new Role(1L, role, null));
        userService.addUser(user);
        Mockito.verify(roleRepositoryMock).findByRole(role);
        Mockito.verify(userRepositoryMock).save(user);
    }

    @Test
    void shouldThrowAlreadyRegisteredException() {
        UserService userService = new UserService(userRepositoryMock, roleRepositoryMock);
        String email = "yes@gmail.com";
        User user = new User(0L, "test", "test", email, "yesyesyes", new ArrayList<>(), null);
        Mockito.when(userRepositoryMock.findByEmail(email)).thenReturn(user);
        Exception exception = assertThrows(UserAlreadyRegisteredException.class, () -> userService.addUser(user));
        Assert.assertEquals("User already registered", exception.getMessage());
    }


    @Test
    void invalidPasswordTest() {
        UserService userService = new UserService(null, null);
        String password = "qwert";
        assertFalse(userService.passwordValidator(password));
    }

}
```

Been learning Spring boot recently and wrote a simple CRUD api, I have never done any kind of testing before and this is my first attempt writing tests for service layer

Comment: Could you please [edit] so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code under test?  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews - knowing that these are your first tests doesn't help with that.  Thanks!

Comment: You're starting to learn unit testing? Well, I wish *I* had seen this before I started doing unit tests... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ05e7EMOLM

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The test looks good. except that you do not have to initialize the `UserService` again inside the Test like below, since `@BeforeEach` is being called every time before each test

```
  @Test
    void shouldThrowAlreadyRegisteredException() {
UserService userService = new UserService(userRepositoryMock, roleRepositoryMock);
}
```